# Determine the Value of C of the matrix which Matrix A is not invertible

Tags: matrices

Determine the value(s) of C for which the matrix of

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -2\\0 & 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 1&C \end{bmatrix}$

is not invertible. For all Other values of C , Find $\ A^{-1} \ $

what i have done  is  the inverse of the  $\ A^{-1} = {{1} \over Det(A)}* Adj(A)= {{1}\over {2C}} $ and i got $\ {1\over2c} * {\begin{bmatrix}2c-4 & 4 & -2\\-2 & c+2 & 1 \\ 4 & -4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}}$

How am I supposed to go further ?

Answer (score 2):

Observe
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 2 & 4\\
1  & 1 & C
\end{bmatrix}
\sim 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 2 & 4\\
0  & 1 & C+2
\end{bmatrix}
\sim 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 1 & 2\\
0  & 1 & C+2
\end{bmatrix}
\sim 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 1 & 2\\
0  & 0 & C
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: which means that $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -2\\0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0&C \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ means C=0 where x1= 2(x3) and X2= -2(x3) where X3=0 therefore both X1 and X2 is 0?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find the value of $C$ is to notice that clearly the first two rows are linearly independent.

The matrix is invertible if and only if the third row lies in the span of the first two rows.

Hence $$R_1+\frac12 R_2=R_3$$

$$-2+\frac12 (4)=C$$